# parameterised first level state in ui route

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am building a application which has different modules. and two modules can have same pages. So based on url i am making the appropriate ajax call to load data. So I am tring to setup my states in below way:

```
$stateProvider.state('login', {
    url: '/login',
    templateUrl: 'login.html',
    controller: 'LoginController as LoginController'
}).state('logout', {
    url: '/logout',
    templateUrl: '',
    controller: 'LogoutController as LogoutController'
}).state('module', {
    url: '/:module',
    params: {
        module: DataService.getCurrentModule()
    }
}).state('module.cover', {
    url: '/cover',
    templateUrl: 'cover.html',
    params: {
        module: 'leads'
    }
}).state('module.leads', {
    url: '/leads',
    templateUrl: 'leads.html',
    controller: 'LeadsController as ctrl',
    abstract: true
})
```

Given that at the time of login I will fetch all modules and save it in DataService, which is happening. Then after login two things will be done. One navigation urls which i have formatted in below way:

```
<a href={'#/'+ module.code +"/" + (menu.type|| menu)}>
    <i className={classes}></i> <span >{menu.name || menu }</span>
</a>
```

which is setting the correct url, and second in app.js in "run" I am checking if login is done them I am doing :
    $location.path(DataService.getCurrentModule() + "/" +  (home.type || home) );

which is also happening, but issue is desired controller and html page is not being loaded. Am I missing something here. Or should I have done things little differently?

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid `href` when working with `ui.router`. To navigate to the required states use:

- In HTML: `ui-sref="myStateName({param1: 1, param2: 2})"`
- In Javascript inject the service `$state` and do: `$state.go('myStateName', {param1: 1, param2: 2});`

In your case, lets assume that there are 2 modules in an array in the $scope:

```
$scope.myModules = [{code: 'modA'},{code: 'modB'}];
```

Now in the HTML, to go to the `module.cover` state you would do:

```
<a ui-sref="module.cover({module: myModules[0].code})">My Link</a>
```

If you want to do it for all modules, put it inside an `ng-repeat`:

```
<a ng-repeat="mod in modules" ui-sref="module.cover({module: mod.code})">My Link</a>
```

Also, for state configuration, consider:

- **ALL STATES NEED A TEMPLATE**: even if they are abstract states, they require a template to work properly. If the parent state doesn't have a template, not even one of its childs is gonna show. In this case, the state `module` doesn't have a template, so it will never work. define a template for it as simple as `template: '<div ui-view></div>'`
- When you define a parameter in the URL, there's no need to define it again in with a `params` property. That is used only when you need parameters that you don't want to show in the URL